# how to set QPixmap as brush for rectangle properly?

Tags: qt, paint, qpixmap

i want to set a `QPixmap` as brush for a rectangle in `paint` method .I do this work but it doesn't set accurately .I test many value for width and height but yet it wasn't good .Overall, what sizes  should I set for  the rectangle surrounding the photo that put in it properly?

```
void set_coin::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem  *option,)
{
QRectF rec(x_size,y_size,10,30);
QPixmap coin(":pictures/image/coin.jpg");
coin=coin.scaled(10,30);
painter->setBrush(QBrush(coin));
painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
//painter->drawRect(rec);
painter->drawRoundedRect(rec,10,10);
}
QRectF set_coin::boundingRect() const
{
  return QRectF(x_size-10,y_size-10,20,40);
}
```

[image: i want it]
[image: What is shown in program(i put 4 coin in my scene)]

Comment: Can you edit your post by adding an image of what you get and an other of what you want please ?

Comment: i want to have that complete coin.in another image i put 4 coin in my scene but are shown incompletely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

`QRectF rec(x_size,y_size,10,30);`

The doc says:

`QRectF::QRectF ( qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height )`

The last two arguments are x_size and y_size, not the first two one ;)

EDIT: (Because I didn't really understand the problem first)

I tried your code and in fact, your image is not "accuracy" because you see 4 pieces of mage on your small 10 to 30 area.

The solution is to set x_size (respectively y_size) a value which is a multiple of 10 (respectively 30).

If you try x_size = 100 and y_size = 300, it will works ;)

Comment: i know this.`greal width` =10 `greal height`=30.these are my rectangle 's dimensions.

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you again.i test with 100,300.it was good.but in my application i have some bricks that i want to put these coins on their.it means `x_size` and `y_size` is changeable.i deal with problem before for another images.is there a way that solve it? is related This problem to the dimensions of the original photo?(144x152 pixels)